# C++: Encoding H264 with FFmpeg, unable to set preset

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-encoding, libav

I'm trying to encode H.264 movie with FFmpeg/libAV, when I try to set the codec preset the return code indicates an error:

```
...

mContext.codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

mContext.stream = avformat_new_stream(mContext.format_context, nullptr);
mContext.stream->id = (int)(mContext.format_context->nb_streams - 1);

mContext.codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(mContext.codec);

int ret;
ret = av_opt_set(mContext.codec_context->priv_data, "preset", "medium", 0);

// returns -1414549496

...
```

I ommited error checking for brevity in the example.

I tried setting `preset` to different values ("medium", "slow", "veryslow" etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not reproducible.

In following code sample `av_opt_set` returns `0`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
#include "libavutil/opt.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
}

int main()
{
    AVOutputFormat* ofmt = av_guess_format("h264", nullptr, nullptr); //H.264

    if (ofmt == nullptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

    if (codec == nullptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    AVFormatContext* format_context = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (format_context == nullptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&format_context, ofmt, nullptr, nullptr);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    AVStream* stream = avformat_new_stream(format_context, nullptr);

    if (stream == nullptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    stream->id = (int)(format_context->nb_streams - 1);

    AVCodecContext* codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

    if (codec_context == nullptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ret = av_opt_set(codec_context->priv_data, "preset", "medium", 0);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("Error: av_opt_set returned: %d\n", ret);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The above code checks for errors after each step.

There are no errors...

---

My guess is that your version of FFmpeg does not include libx264 encoder.
`avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264)` returns other H.264 encoder (not `libx264`).
The other encoder doesn't have the `medium` preset option.

Try forcing `libx264` encoder by replacing `AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);` with:

```
AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264");
```

In case `codec == nullptr`, your FFmpeg does not include libx264 encoder.

---

It's only a guess...

In case it's not the issue, please post an executable code sample.

Comment: Yes, ultimately this was the issue - after compiling the FFmpeg with libx264 support everything started working as intended. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ret = av_opt_set(mContext.codec_context->priv_data, "preset", "medium", 0);
>
> // returns -1414549496
> ```

I don't think you're allowed to touch `priv_data`. Why don't you call `av_opt_set()` on the `codec_context` directly? See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146587/how-do-you-enable-veryfast-libx264-preset-from-code-using-libavcodec).

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment under @rotem answer, it was due to missing libx264, but thanks for pointing to the post about AVDictionary, I actually rewrote the code to utilize it.